# Using cell value as range reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I’m have the following macro that is linked to a shape (as if if it was a button):

```
Sub circulo()
    Dim SSLeft As Double
    Dim SSTop As Double
    Dim SSWidth As Double
    Dim SSHeight As Double
    Dim shpOval As Shape
    Dim SS As Range
    Dim SS1 As String
    Set SS = SS1
    Set SS1 = Range("AO24").Text
    SSLeft = SS.Left
    SSTop = SS.Top
    SSHeight = SS.Height
    SSWidth = SS.Width
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, SSLeft, SSTop, 20, 20)
End Sub
```

What it is supposed to do is create a shape (Oval) on the cell (`C8`) that is referenced from another cell (`AO24`). In cell `AO24` I have the following formula:

```
=""""&SUSTITUTE(CELL("ADRESS",INDEX(B7:H7,1,MATCH(AN24,B7:H7,0))),"$","")&""""
```

It searches the value of the cell `AN24` (a date) in some range (`B7:H7`), giving the result `C8`. What is supposed to happen is that the macro will get the value from the cell(`AO24`) and will make it a range so it will add the shape to the cell that the formula is giving (`C8` in this case) but it doesn’t happen, I try to make it this way because the value of `AO24` will change dynamically.

Any help on the right way to do this will be appreciated.

Edit: it's not spelling, the formula was translated, so originally it works.

Comment: maybe correcting the spelling helps ? `SUSTITUTE`=>`SUBSTITUTE`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your Code are,

`Dim SS1 As String` and  `Set SS1 = Range("AO24").Text`.

Actually Variable SS1 data type must be **Range** and `Set SS1 =  Range("AO24")`.

Now you are trying to create a Dynamic Range to create Shape, but in this case Excel VBA only reads the Cell Address and will make Shape in Cell AO24.

I would like to recommend you to use `Range(Selection.Address)` so that you can select the Cell where you want to draw the Shape.

Check the below written code help you to create Shape in Active Cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()

  Dim clLeft As Double
  Dim clTop As Double
  Dim clWidth As Double
  Dim clHeight As Double

  Dim cl As Range
  Dim shpOval As Shape

      Set cl = Range(Selection.Address)
        'Set cl = Range("AO24")

          clLeft = cl.Left
            clTop = cl.Top
              clHeight = cl.Height
                clWidth = cl.Width

       Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, clLeft, clTop, 40, 10)

Debug.Print shpOval.Left = clLeft
Debug.Print shpOval.Top = clTop

End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*